# Add an existing project of Visual Studio 2019 to Visual SourceSafe

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, visual-sourcesafe, visual-sourcesafe-2005

I have a project and I would like to add it to Visual SourceSafe 2005, but I can't find a way.
Is there a solution for this? or is not compatible Visual Studio 2019 with Visual SourceSafe 2005?

Comment: why do you want to use such an old an buggy source code versioning tool? it is better to use Git/Subversion.

Answer (score -1):

```
File --> Create Project ..
File --> Add Files ...
```